# Elapsed time between application accepted and running states

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm working with a yarn cluster managing spark, mr and tez applications. I'd like to calculate the average time elapsed to pass from the accepted state to the running state for all the finished applications. My question are:

- Is there an easier way to do that rather than parsing the logs of
  each single past application and substract timestamps
- Does yarn already provide a similar metric (basically something to estimate applications average waiting time before running)

Thanks!

Comment: I am not an expert in this area but I quickly reviewed the code in RMAppImpl. It seems that the only way to measure elapsed time from ACCEPTED to RUNNING is indeed to rely on the "State change from" log statement. You might want to explore what the history server REST API provides. It does not store such fine-grained info but perhaps the difference between job.submitTime and min(taskAttempt.startTime) is a good enough approximation.

Answer (score 2):

For every YARN application, you can keep track of the Application ID. By making REST calls to the `Timeline Server (Port 8188)` and `JobHistory Server (Port 19888)` by using this Application ID, you can figure out the required time.

## For MR

Every application has a default name in the format `application_<epoch time at the submission>_<4-digit index number>`. Replace the `application_` at the start with `job_` and you get the Job ID. Now make a REST call to the HistoryServer using the following format of URL:

```
http://<IP of your cluster-manager>:19888/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs/<Job ID>
```

You'll get an XML or JSON Response (it's) with the fields `submitTime` and `startTime`. They are in epoch milliseconds. The difference is the required value.

## For TEZ

For TEZ, the monitoring is done in terms of the Directed-Acyclic Graphs that get associated with each application. So, you need to get intuitive and make the following REST call:

```
http://<IP of your cluster-manager>:8188/ws/v1/timeline/TEZ_DAG_ID
```

You get a big response. For every DAG ID, you need to look into the `Primary Identifiers` of the DAG and you'll find the Application ID associated with each DAG. Simply get the `submitTime` and `startTime` for the application and take the difference.

### Things that may help you:

1. Install JSONView extension if you use Chrome, this can help you go through the output of your REST calls.
2. If you are using a cluster managed by a manager like Ambari or Cloudera Manager, you can go to TEZ Web UI and find out the details of your TEZ applications in much more detail.
3. For MR Jobs, you can do the similar thing by visiting the History Server by typing in your browser `http://<IP of your cluster-manager>:19888` and look at the application-data from there.

Answer (score 0):

How do  we get the submit time for a spark job?

I tried the http::18080/api/v1/applications api, but it doesnot provide submit time.